# Is this a correct definition of stationary process?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, stationary-processes

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space, let $(E,\mathcal E$) a measurable space. Let $(X_n)_n$ be a succession of random variable from $\Omega$ to $E$. We consider the whole $(X_n)_n$ as a block function from $\Omega$ to $E^{\mathbb N^*}$, the space of all successions of elements of $E$. Let $\mathcal E^{\mathbb N^*}$ be its associated $\sigma$-algebra. Finally, define the left-shift function $\tau$.

Then $(X_n)_n: \Omega \to E^{\mathbb N^*}$ is stationary if, for every $B\in\mathcal E^{\mathbb N^*}$,

$
\mathbb P((X_n)_n^{-1}(B)) = \mathbb P((X_n)_n^{-1}(\tau(B)))
$

I have the feeling that this is close to a correct definition, even if I left out a lot of details.

EDIT:
Alternatively, how can I define a stationary sequence of random variables using only image-measures? I am a bit confused.

Comment: I think this is equivalent to the usual definition of stationarity written in terms of finite dimensional distributions.

Comment: Would you recommend using another definition?